# Dart: How to connect to a IP address

Tags: dart, http, dns, dart-io

I am creating java okhttp3 in dart named okhttp and was working on dns over https (doh).

Currently I am able to do dns resolution successfully but after I have obtained the internet addresses of the host I don't know what to do with it.

I have tried replacing the host with the address and it throws handshake exception and always fails to connect and i have also tried to connect to the address socket and that throws redirect loop detected.